# When a recipe call for 2 part of table salt plus 1 part of lawry’s seasoned salt how much salt is that

Tags: salt

2 part of table salt plus 1 part of lawry’s seasoned salt.  How much salt is that.

Comment: The quote alone says nothing at all about the total volume, just the ratio of the two components. Hopefully there's more context somewhere

Comment: The question is unclear.  As pointed out above, is this parts by volume?  or mass / weight?  is your confusion about the meaning of the word "part" in this context"?  or are you asking about the final sodium / salt content of whatever recipe you are making?  Where did this come from?  What recipe are you citing?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean **Lawry's** *seasoned salt* the ratio of salt to "other ingredients" (i.e. "seasoning" - sugar, spices, etc.) appears to give a total (with 2 parts salt) of about 2.67 parts salt by volume, depending which particular "plain table salt" nutrition label you look at (they vary more than I expected.)

By weight, 2.83 parts

I'm using sodium content as a proxy for salt.

[image: Lawry's nutrition label]

*[Image Source](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.us-shop-berlin.de%2FWebRoot%2FStore9%2FShops%2F63282115%2F4FD7%2F1853%2F8BBC%2FDBF9%2FB97C%2FC0A8%2F29C0%2F2450%2F58519r.jpg&f=1&nofb=1&ipt=d4910c0ac7f29597ec816032bcf13c101e8dd72cd50512d3a821dc4137bd2961&ipo=images) no affiliation*